# Getting the response twice on every time in skype channel

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015, botframework, skype

Hi I am working on bots and It’s working fine in local bot emulator as well as bot channel’s.

Here my problem is when I am using bot application in skype, the response coming from bot twice in every time and rest of the channels its working fine.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve the issue in bots ?

Comment: Can you share your bot code that is causing the issue?

Comment: Could you please share some code or steps that can lead us to reproduce your issue?

Comment: This is the link for sample code of my bot application        https://1drv.ms/w/s!AplEuMCGZqsWiZY7TBOBQENBpfSx5Q

Comment: I think there is no code issue because I already publish the same code in to channels like slack and Facebook messenger, they are working fine in that channels but the only problem is skype only.